# How to uninstall a manual configuration of PHP 5.2.17 on CentOS 6.7 (Final)

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, php, mysql

Centos 6.7 (Final) comes with PHP 5.3.3, but the site running on the server needed PHP 5.2.17. Because it is not supported much anymore I manually configured PHP 5.2.17 using this guide: [PHP Configuration Guide](https://www.webcorecloud.com/blog/2013/01/16/compiling-php-5217-centos-6/)

I got PHP 5.2.17 configured on the server, yet that didn't fix the errors I was having, so I am trying to revert back to 5.3.3.

**php -v**  returns:

PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Oct 27 2015 13:53:42)

Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

**yum list installed | grep php**  returns:

atomic-php52-php-eaccelerator.x86_64

php.x86_64 5.3.3-46.el6_6 @updates

php-cli.x86_64                  5.3.3-46.el6_6            @updates

php-common.x86_64               5.3.3-46.el6_6            @updates

php-devel.x86_64                5.3.3-46.el6_6            @updates

php-gd.x86_64                   5.3.3-46.el6_6            @updates

php-ldap.x86_64                 5.3.3-46.el6_6            @updates

php-mbstring.x86_64             5.3.3-46.el6_6            @updates

php-mcrypt.x86_64               5.3.3-4.el6               @epel

php-mssql.x86_64                5.3.3-4.el6               @epel

php-mysql.x86_64                5.3.3-46.el6_6            @updates

php-odbc.x86_64                 5.3.3-46.el6_6            @updates

php-pdo.x86_64                  5.3.3-46.el6_6            @updates

php-pear.noarch                 1:1.9.4-4.el6             @base

php-pgsql.x86_64                5.3.3-46.el6_6            @updates

php-snmp.x86_64                 5.3.3-46.el6_6            @updates

Comment: Ok so you're trying to revert, What's your question to us exactly? Where are you getting stuck reverting?  What happens if you simply revert the actions you took when you followed the guide you've linked?

Comment: I guess that's my question, how do I go about reverting it? As I haven't uninstalled php5.3.3, can I just remove the php folder that I configured or do I need to like, unconfigure php5.2.17?

Comment: Just undo the changes you made while following the guide...  where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure how to undo the changes... How do I reconfigure my php to be 5.3 again?

Comment: Okay I got it. I just had to do a yum install of everything again, oddly simple.